# Javascript sort items excluding some specific items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, canjs

I am trying to sort some items (sort a map) , I can sort it successfully, but I want to exclude some items based on it's attribute

Right now I am sorting like this based on attribute - price

```
 return (product.attr('active') !== 'f'
                }).sort(function(pA,pB){
                  return pB.attr('price') - pA.attr('price'); });
```

I want to skip some items based on `attr('product_id')` so the listed product_id's wont be sorted based, and will be returned first.

```
return (product.attr('active') !== 'f'
      }).sort(function(pA,pB){
   return pB.attr('price') - pA.attr('price'); }).except(pA.attr('product_id') == 5677));
```

Something like above, obviously except function does not exist.

Is there a way to exclude some items from sorting, based on it's attributes like id?

Data

```
Map
active
:
true
brand_id
:
1
categories
:
Map(2) ["All Products", "Snacks", _cid: ".map232", _computedAttrs: {…}, __bindEvents: {…}, _comparatorBound: false, _bubbleBindings: {…}, …]
channel_id
:
1
created
:
"2017-08-14T19:16:56.148029-07:00"
description
:
"Breakfast"
image
:
"/media/333807.png"
name
:
"Breakfast"
price
:
"1"
product_id
:
5677
```

Comment: Can you show us your data?

Comment: Please provide an example of your inputs and your expected result.

Comment: Data is posted @void

Comment: Can you please format it now?

Comment: do you have more than one item to sort to top?

Comment: @NinaScholz can be more than one items not a single item

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "skip". Do you want to filter them out, i.e. remove them completely from the result, or do you just want to sort these specific items always first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the wanted item to front by using a check and return the delta of the check.

```js
var array = [{ product_id: 1, price: 1 }, { product_id: 2, price: 3 }, { product_id: 3, price: 4 }, { product_id: 4, price: 1 }, { product_id: 5, price: 8 }, { product_id: 5677, price: 1 }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.product_id === 5677) - (a.product_id === 5677) || b.price - a.price;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With more than just one id for sorting to top

```js
var array = [{ product_id: 1, price: 1 }, { product_id: 2, price: 3 }, { product_id: 3, price: 4 }, { product_id: 4, price: 1 }, { product_id: 5, price: 8 }, { product_id: 5677, price: 1 }];
    topIds = [5677, 2]

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return topIds.includes(b.product_id) - topIds.includes(a.product_id) || b.price - a.price;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How can I make it work for multiple product_id's? I need to exclude more than one `product_id`

Comment: do the top items need a special sorting, despite of the standard descending sorting by `price`?

Comment: No, top items do not need a special sorting. Will this work with other stand descending sorting by name, date and other sorting methods?

Comment: you could chain the other sorting criteria with logical OR behind the price sorting.

Comment: It excludes those items for sorting, for sure, but it's being returned last, I need to return it first

Comment: then just switch `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thank you so much, everything works, except, what is the best way to work this when comparing names `if (nameA < nameB) return  -1; if(nameA > nameB) return 1; return 0; });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165682/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-cowgirl).